# Flutter google_mobile_ads not showing with ad id

Tags: flutter, admob, google-mobile-ads

I am using [google_mobile_ads](https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads/changelog) and have verified my admob account and created the ad units, all of em are atleast 2 days old.

But whenever i change the ad id, in the below code, the ads don't show up. I tried building a release apk and installing it on my phone, but the ads still don't show and I have not released the app yet.

```dart
void loadRewardedAd(){
    RewardedAd.load(
        adUnitId: RewardedAd.testAdUnitId,//when i put my ad id here it doesn't work
        request: AdRequest(),
        rewardedAdLoadCallback: RewardedAdLoadCallback(
          onAdLoaded: (RewardedAd ad) {
            rewardedAd = ad;
            adLoadsNumber = 0;
          },
          onAdFailedToLoad: (LoadAdError error) {
            adLoadsNumber++;
            interStitialAd = null;

            if (adLoadsNumber <= 2) {
              loadAds();
            }
          },
        ));
  }

  void showRewardedAd(){
    rewardedAd.fullScreenContentCallback = FullScreenContentCallback(
      onAdShowedFullScreenContent: (RewardedAd ad) =>
          print('$ad onAdShowedFullScreenContent.'),
      onAdDismissedFullScreenContent: (RewardedAd ad) {
        print('$ad onAdDismissedFullScreenContent.');
        ad.dispose();
      },
      onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: (RewardedAd ad, AdError error) {
        print('$ad onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: $error');
        ad.dispose();
      },
      onAdImpression: (RewardedAd ad) => print('$ad impression occurred.'),
    );

    rewardedAd.show(
        onUserEarnedReward: (RewardedAd ad, RewardItem rewardItem) {
          this.gameEnded = false;
          this.livesLeft.value = 3;
        }
    );

  }
  void loadAds() {
    loadInterstitialAd();
    loadRewardedAd();
  }

  void loadInterstitialAd(){
    InterstitialAd.load(
        adUnitId: InterstitialAd.testAdUnitId,//same with this one
        request: AdRequest(),
        adLoadCallback:
        InterstitialAdLoadCallback(onAdLoaded: (InterstitialAd ad) {
          interStitialAd = ad;
          adLoadsNumber = 0;
        }, onAdFailedToLoad: (LoadAdError e) {
          adLoadsNumber++;
          interStitialAd = null;

          if (adLoadsNumber <= 2) {
            loadInterstitialAd();
          }
        }));
  }

  void showInterstitialAd(bool isEnded) {
    if (interStitialAd == null) {
      return;
    }

    interStitialAd.fullScreenContentCallback = FullScreenContentCallback(
      onAdDismissedFullScreenContent: (InterstitialAd ad) {
        ad.dispose();
      },
      onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: (InterstitialAd ad, AdError error) {
        ad.dispose();
      },
    );

    interStitialAd.show();
  }
```

Comment: I have signed the release apk too

Comment: If test ads are showing then it is completely fine, Live Ads take quite some time to be shown.

Comment: ok, test ads are shown. thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Please check did you added Signed APK SHA in the console.**

Comment: I hav signed it using a keystore using this https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android but i haven't signed it using sha, is it necessary to do so?